# Connect desktop application with application server and Database

Tags: java, web-applications, desktop-application

I have a design problem about how to connect Desktop Java application which needs to read and write from Database. Which one of the two approaches is better?

1. Connect the Desktop Java application directly to the Database using JDBC driver over the network. This is very bad idea because if the security but it will be very easy to write SQL queries directly and execute them.
2. Connect the Java Desktop application to Application server which will be connected to the Database. In this case how I'm going to do the SQL queries? I need some kind of a tunnel which will be used to transfer the queries and return the output. This is approach is very secure but the response time will be big.

Can you tell me are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to use EJB Server.

Create an EJB Inteface with all the crud methods (save,delete ,update etc).

Create an EJB Implementation on the server (Jboss/GlassFish) .

Once the server is up and running then just copy the Interface Jar file to your application(java Swing App) and using JNDI you can call all the crud operations.

~I hope that helps.

Comment: i agree. In some cases this could be a little oversized, but generally this is a good option, too.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @desperateCoder but its quite robust solution.

Comment: hi Makky, I am also really intersted in this topic. I saw that you said is: " Once the server is up and running then just copy the Interface Jar file to your application(java Swing App) and using JNDI you can call all the crud operations." but I am also abit confused for example in case of my application client is running on another machine with my Application Server where the EJB Implementation is running on, how can they communicate?. If they are in the same project structure then we can copy the interface jar file easily but how that if they are in different enviroment?

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to solve this problem. It is not possible to recommend one over the other without knowing more about your application and its requirements.

Approaches that come to mind are e.g. EJB, SOAP, REST, JDBC/JPA/Hibernate, RMI.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to host a webservice on the application server with all the CRUD operations. This makes it more portable in sense of client implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree, a public Database is baggin for being hacked! but why does it have to be an application server? a lightweight server-component of your application could do the trick, too? you even could send objects over the network (ObjectOutputStream)

I already did the same thing as i described, works horribly fine, and is super simple, since i am using reflection in combination with generics to execute the right query.

Answer (score 1):

Your application server is exposing DataSources which can provide you a Connection object (more information there : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html). The connection between your app and the database will be direct so there is no impact on performances.

Comment: Could you, please give me some more information how I can do this using prepared statements?

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility of performing SQL queries should be only given to the application server. All the intelligence should be transferred to the application server.

As described in the previous answers this can be done by using [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans), [web services](https://jax-ws.java.net/) (performances should be a bit lower but that way you can interact with any other system, even with web client) and [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation).

Please also consider the solutions given by [Spring](http://www.springsource.org).